# My django project is not importing files from the same directory

Tags: python, django

```
from django.urls import path
from .entries import views
  
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('add/', views.add)
]
```

This is my code..I am getting this error:

```
from .entries import views
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent 
package
```

Comment: Can you show your folder structure? maybe a `tree` output.

Answer (score 0):

you need to name the imported views. try with:

```
from entries import views as entries_views
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.urls import path
from entries import views
  
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('add', views.add)
]
```

write like this
Your Mistack is : `from **.**entries import views`
remove this .(dot)

I hope this information help you